How to identify an NTFS volume with a null-GUID? (Windows 10)
Every day, I get some 4 or 5 NTFS error logs like this:
NTFS failed to mount the volume.

           Error: {Device Offline}
The printer has been taken offline.
           Volume GUID: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
           Volume Name: 

Guidance:
The volume is recognized by NTFS but it is corrupted that NTFS 
could not mount it. Run CHKDSK /F to fix any errors on this volume, 
and then try accessing it.

Details:
- System 
  - Provider 
      [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-Ntfs 
      [ Guid]  {3ff37a1c-a68d-4d6e-8c9b-f79e8b16c482} 
    EventID 305 
    Version 0 
    Level 2 
    Task 6 
    Opcode 2 
    Keywords 0x4000000000000020 
  - Execution 
      [ ProcessID]  4 
      [ ThreadID]  15656 
    Channel Microsoft-Windows-Ntfs/Operational 
- EventData 
  Error 0x80000010 
  VolumeGuid {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} 
  VolumeNameLength 0 
  VolumeName  

Does someone have an idea how I can get rid of these? It seems that there is a printer driver that somehow is related to an NTFS volume that the system can't mount (anymore).
I have deleted all the printers, but their drivers and ports are still there (Print Management).
